# what is the purpose of Windows.Data.Xml.Dom

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store

I have a basic question on XML handling in Windows Runtime - why is the new `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom` namespace introduced when already there is `X-DOM` and `System.Xml`? What are its advantages when it's a bit clumsier to use than `X-DOM` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, WinRT APIs like this that overlap with other language-specific means, are there because not every language has such services. For example, the JSON API isn't needed in JavaScript (and it's not even projected there), but you do need it for C++. In the Xml.Dom case, it's primarily there for C++ and thus an option for .NET languages.